# Frontier properties of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I am supposed to prove or disprove the following claims:

1. If $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary, then $(Fr(Fr(A))^{\mathbb{o}} = \emptyset$
2. If $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary, then $Fr(A \times B) = (Fr(A) \times B) \cup (A \times Fr(B))$

It seems the latter claim is correct, but I cannot prove it.  It's not hard to visualize. On the other hand, I have no idea about the first claim.

Comment: What is the frontier of a set?

Comment: I suppose other notations for $Fr(A)$ are $Bd(A)$ or $\partial A$.

Comment: So it's what I would call the [boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology))? Would you look at that, the article even mentions that some authors use "frontier". I learned something today.

Comment: So you are not using the other definition of frontier $(\partial A)-A$?  The second claim is false if $A,B$ are not closed.

Comment: What do you mean by "the other definition of frontier"?  Did you mean $Cl(A) \setminus Int(A)$?

Comment: No, there are two different definitions of frontier in the literature: either as a synonym of the boundary $\operatorname{Fr}A:=\partial A=\overline{A}-A^\circ$, or as the set of points in the closure that is not already in $A$, $\operatorname{Fr}A:=\overline{A}-A$.

Comment: Our teaching assistant used the definition as a synonym for boundary of a set.

Comment: I'll give you a hint to the first one: prove that $\partial\partial A\subseteq\partial A$ for all $A$.  (Note that $\partial\partial A$ is not necessarily empty, e.g., Kuratowski's closure-complement problem).

Comment: So, in a nutshell, every element of $\partial \partial A$ is in the closures of sets $\partial A$ and complement of $\partial A$, hence it is in closure of $\partial A$, i.e. in $\partial A$.  Now it is sufficient to prove that $Int(\partial A) $ is $\emptyset$, but is it correct for all sets? As I recall it was posted here that there is an equivalent condition to this condition...

Comment: @NemanjaBeric No, the interior of the boundary can be $\mathbb{R}$, consider $A = \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- the boundary of a closed set or an open set has empty interior.
- the boundary of any set is closed.

Together this implies that $\operatorname{int}(\partial \partial A) = \emptyset$ for any $A$, the first boundary operation makes it closed and then the boundary of a closed set has empty interior.

Fact 2 is refuted by $A = B =\mathbb{Q}$, as $(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q}) \cup (\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}) \neq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. IIRC, we need a term $\partial A \times \partial B$ in the union as well.